# Fact check probability De Morgan's Law

Tags: probability-theory

[image]

Is the statement about the De Morgan's Law application correct? Isn't there a ''c'' (compliment) too many?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be more familiar with: $(A\cap B)^{\complement}=A^\complement\cup B^\complement$; thus: $$\left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right)^{\!\!\complement} ~=~ \left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty {A_i}^{\!\!\complement}\right)$$

Just take the complement of both sides, and cancel (the complement of a complement of a set *is* the set itself):

$$\require{cancel}\left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right)^{\!\!\cancel[color=silver]{{\complement\complement}}} ~=~ \left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty {A_i}^{\!\!\complement}\right)^{\!\!\complement}$$