# Filling $N$ boxes with $K$ balls without using the Boole inequality.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have $N=100$ boxes with $K$ balls. For the experiment, I toss $K$ balls into the $N$ boxes, every ball is guaranteed to go into a box.

I want to know how big $K$ must be such that the probability of each box having a ball in it is at least $0.95$.

I was able to "solve" this by using Boole's inequality but that only provides me an approximation for low values of N.

Comment: This is a slightly disguised version of the Coupon Collector's Problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Comment: For large $n$, the number of balls is approximately $n\log(20n)$.

Comment: If you provide more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960), then this question might get more answers.

Comment: @robjohn: your $n \log(20n) \approx 760$ when $n=100$ is a pretty good approximation.  The actual figure is $754$

Comment: @Henry: If there were more context provided, I would post the approach I used to get that approximation.

Comment: @Henry: actually, the $20$ is $-\frac1{\log(.95)}\approx19.5$

Comment: @robjohn: and indeed $n \log\left(-\frac{n}{\log(0.95)}\right) \approx 757.5$ when $100$ is better.  But using the R code `library(gmp);asNumeric(Stirling2(754,100)*factorial(100)/as.bigz(100)^754)` I get `0.950022`

Comment: @Henry: Of course. The formula I gave inverts an approximation, so there will be some unresolved error.

Comment: I'm not sure what other context to provide.  I am trying to solve a covering problem and boiled it down to this form which is the simpilest way I can think to present the problem.

Comment: @brahadeesh I updated question. Can we reopen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_i$ be the event that the box $i$ is empty, and let $O_i=E_i^c$ be its complement (box is occupied). Notice first that the events $O_i$ are not independent.

But ([de Morgan's Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766108/fact-check-probability-de-morgans-law)) $$p=P(\cap O_i) = 1- P(\cup E_i) \tag{1}$$

and ([Boole's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality))

$$P(\cup E_i)\le \sum P(E_i)=n \left( \frac{n-1}{n}\right)^k \tag{2}$$

The latter comes from noting that the event $E_i$ correspond to having all $k$ balls in some of the others $n-1$ boxes. Each bll has a probability of $(n-1)/n$ of falling in another box. Then the probability that all balls fall in other boxes is the product over the $k$ balls, i.e $ P(E_i)=\left( \frac{n-1}{n}\right)^k$

Hence

$$ p\ge 1- n \left( \frac{n-1}{n}\right)^k \tag{3}$$

From this, setting $p=0.95$  and $n=100$ you can get $k$.

Because $n$ is large, we can (not necessary) approximate $(1- 1/n)^n\to e^{-1}$ to get $ k \approx n \log(20n)$  (as in robjohn's comment)

There are other ways of attacking this, but I guess that this is what you are after for. ( But, please, next time, try to add context, tell us  what you know, what you have tried, etc. It's no fun to guess your context, and to imagine that (perhaps - I hope not) you will simply copy this answer for solving some homework without even thinking and trying to understand. The point is to learn. Welcome to MSE.)

Comment: Thank you.  I am unsure what other context to add.  I am attempting to solve a much more complicated problem but was able to boil it down to the analogy given but that is where i got stuck.  I tried Binomial and hypergeometric but the former assumes replacement and the latter doesnt account for the fact you could have more than 1 ball per box.

Comment: How did you get n((n-1)/n)^k?  I also don't understand why you started with E's and then switched to Os.

Comment: FOr the first, I added some exaplanation. $E$ is simply the complement of $O$ , I'm not sure what is your doubt here.

Comment: If Ec = O, then why not just say 1-P(UOc)?

Comment: Is there a type here: " Each box has a probability of (n−1)/n of falling in another box"

Comment: Typo fixed. Yes, you can write $O_i^c$ instead of $E_i$, if you prefer, I just felt that the following formulas get a little cleaner. No big deal.

Comment: I dont understand this line: "Let Ei be the event that the box i has at least a ball, and let Oi=Eci be its complement (box is occupied)." Wouldnt it Oi be the event that box i is NOT occupied?

Comment: Oh, dear. That was a typo.Fixed. Sorry for that.

Comment: I have studied your solution more and it looks like it is not exact. You use Boole's inequality which ignores a bunch of terms for the union.

Comment: @Avedis My solution "is not exact" in the sense that it only gives a bound, it's not an equality but an inequality. If you mean that, you are right, of course, but that was obvious - and that was enough for solving your problem. If you instead mean that my bound in itself is not exact, please clarify where do you find an error.